# Objective-c Web/URL preview as in facebook app

Tags: objective-c, webview

In facebook app, when we post url, it can show small preview page. When we tap on that, it will go to that url page.

Is it possible to do preview page with webview? If so, may I know how to do? If not, what method shall I use to show preview?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)];  
webView.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.my_url.com"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: myTimeoutValue];  
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```